# Why fragment is over textView?

Tags: android

I have layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/frag1"
            class="com.luheb.cars.LastListFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            tools:layout="@layout/frag1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

In fragment I have `ListView` and if I click on `TextView` then **onclick** from `ListView` is calling.

I want `TextView` have on bottom and `fragment` with `ListView` should from top to `TextView`. Now `fragment` is from top to bottom and `TextView` is sticky to bottom...

Comment: Try adding attribute `layout_below` to your TextView.

Comment: With layout_below I don't see my TextView...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

[**`android:layout_above`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_above).

> Positions the bottom edge of this view above the given anchor view ID.
>   Accommodates bottom margin of this view and top margin of anchor view.

Finally

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/frag1"
        class="com.luheb.cars.LastListFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/frag1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This line to your fragment:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
```